# Select distinct records based on regexp pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a db with domains. 
I need to pull the domains suffixes and create a list of those suffixes. (.com, .net, .org ...)
I've found that regexp patterns may help me. The only thing I can't make is to filter those domains based on the pattern + uniqueness, in order to get my list. 
Here's my query: 
`$qry="select * from domain where domain_name REGEXP '[[.period.]][a-z]+'";`
How should I add the unique criteria to it?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:** 
Here's the working query: 
`SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', -1) FROM domains WHERE domain_name REGEXP '[[.period.]][a-z]+'`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `[[.period.]]`? I don't think that does what you think it does.

Comment: [[.period.]] is alis for dot '.'.

Comment: All domains should match that regular expression, since they all contain a period followed by letters.

Comment: I understand, so I need the way, to fetch only unique suffixes.

Comment: Doesn't MvG's answer do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has no construct to substitute using regular expressions, or to access matching groups. So regular expressions likely won't help you. Perhaps the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is more useful for you, as you can use that to extract the part after the final dot, using

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', -1) AS tld
```

Comment: I can split them after fetching in PHP, so it's not principal.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've found how to make use of it :) Thanks!